# Scala - Flatten Sequence of EitherT

Tags: scala, scala-cats

Suppose I have the following:

```
val ints: Seq[Int] = ???
def foo(i: Int): EitherT[Future, Error, Seq[String]] = ???
```

I want to invoke the `foo` with the `ints` and accumulate `Seq[String]` result to eventually return `EitherT[Future, Error, Seq[String]]`.

```
ints.map(i => foo(i))
```

Obviously the above returns `Seq[EitherT[Future, Error, Seq[String]]]` and that's not I want. When the `foo` returns `Error` for the first time in the `map`, I want to stop traversing and return the error.

What is the right way to achieve my goal?

Comment: 1) If you tried something, then show it, please. 2) What does "transversally" mean in this context?

Comment: Transversally? According to Google, that means "in a transverse manner." At least that's cleared up!

Comment: Sorry for the confusing wordings. Edited the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ints.map(foo).reduce(for { a <- _ ; b <- _ } yield a ++ b)
```

This basically does what you want, but I don't think it exactly fits the bill for this sentence:

> When the foo returns Error for the first time in the map, I want to
>   stop traversing and return the error.

The issue is that you need to traverse the seq before any of the futures complete, so you don't know if they return errors yet. You could "block" one by one and not make the next call to `foo` until the previous one completes, but then you don't get any parallelism. In theory it might be possible to start all of these futures and then cancel the still-running ones when one returns an error, but cancelling futures is not something that's naturally easy, unfortunately.

Comment: In case there are multiple errors, what does the reduce function reduce the errors to? I mean what will be the eventual error the reduce returns?

Comment: It would be the first error - first in terms of the list order.